# PicoCTF General Skills PW Crack Level4

Tags: python

I'm working on the PW Crack Level4 in the PicoCTF General Skills section. I'm very new to python and CTF's in general. The challenge is to find the right pw from the included list of 100 possibles. I could have, by now, simply entered each one, lol, but that's not the point I think. So I am trying to modify the code to iterate through the list of pw's and pass each one to the part of the code that checks it.

That's where I'm stuck. The for loop seems to run through the list without passing each pw to the part of the code that should check it... I feel like the answer is on the tip of my tongue. But I'm too new to see it.

Here's my code

```
import hashlib

### THIS FUNCTION WILL NOT HELP YOU FIND THE FLAG --LT ########################
def str_xor(secret, key):
    #extend key to secret length
    new_key = key
    i = 0
    while len(new_key) < len(secret):
        new_key = new_key + key[i]
        i = (i + 1) % len(key)        
    return "".join([chr(ord(secret_c) ^ ord(new_key_c)) for (secret_c,new_key_c) in zip(secret,new_key)])
###############################################################################

flag_enc = open('level4.flag.txt.enc', 'rb').read()
correct_pw_hash = open('level4.hash.bin', 'rb').read()


def hash_pw(pw_str):
    pw_bytes = bytearray()
    pw_bytes.extend(pw_str.encode())
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(pw_bytes)
    return m.digest()

pos_pw_list = ["6288", "6152", "4c7a", "b722", "9a6e", "6717", "4389", "1a28", "37ac", "de4f", "eb28", "351b", "3d58", "948b", "231b", "973a", "a087", "384a", "6d3c", "9065", "725c", "fd60", "4d4f", "6a60", "7213", "93e6", "8c54", "537d", "a1da", "c718", "9de8", "ebe3", "f1c5", "a0bf", "ccab", "4938", "8f97", "3327", "8029", "41f2", "a04f", "c7f9", "b453", "90a5", "25dc", "26b0", "cb42", "de89", "2451", "1dd3", "7f2c", "8919", "f3a9", "b88f", "eaa8", "776a", "6236", "98f5", "492b", "507d", "18e8", "cfb5", "76fd", "6017", "30de", "bbae", "354e", "4013", "3153", "e9cc", "cba9", "25ea", "c06c", "a166", "faf1", "2264", "2179", "cf30", "4b47", "3446", "b213", "88a3", "6253", "db88", "c38c", "a48c", "3e4f", "7208", "9dcb", "fc77", "e2cf", "8552", "f6f8", "7079", "42ef", "391e", "8a6d", "2154", "d964", "49ec"]


def level_4_pw_check():
    for x in pos_pw_list: # for loop to iterate through the pos_pw_list
        user_pw = input(x)
        # print(user_pw) # printing user_pw just to make sure the loop is working - it is
        user_pw_hash = hash_pw(user_pw)
    if( user_pw_hash == correct_pw_hash ):
        print("Welcome back... your flag, user:")
        decryption = str_xor(flag_enc.decode(), user_pw)
        print(decryption)
        return
    print("That password is incorrect")



level_4_pw_check()



# The strings below are 100 possibilities for the correct password. 
#   (Only 1 is correct)
pos_pw_list = ["6288", "6152", "4c7a", "b722", "9a6e", "6717", "4389", "1a28", "37ac", "de4f", "eb28", "351b", "3d58", "948b", "231b", "973a", "a087", "384a", "6d3c", "9065", "725c", "fd60", "4d4f", "6a60", "7213", "93e6", "8c54", "537d", "a1da", "c718", "9de8", "ebe3", "f1c5", "a0bf", "ccab", "4938", "8f97", "3327", "8029", "41f2", "a04f", "c7f9", "b453", "90a5", "25dc", "26b0", "cb42", "de89", "2451", "1dd3", "7f2c", "8919", "f3a9", "b88f", "eaa8", "776a", "6236", "98f5", "492b", "507d", "18e8", "cfb5", "76fd", "6017", "30de", "bbae", "354e", "4013", "3153", "e9cc", "cba9", "25ea", "c06c", "a166", "faf1", "2264", "2179", "cf30", "4b47", "3446", "b213", "88a3", "6253", "db88", "c38c", "a48c", "3e4f", "7208", "9dcb", "fc77", "e2cf", "8552", "f6f8", "7079", "42ef", "391e", "8a6d", "2154", "d964", "49ec"]
```

Answer (score 1):

SO I stumbled upon the answer.... it appears to be a indent error (sorry, I don't fully grasp python). But once I properly indented my modified code I got the answer!

```
def level_4_pw_check():
    for x in pos_pw_list: # for loop to iterate through the pos_pw_list
        user_pw = x
        user_pw_hash = hash_pw(user_pw)
        print(user_pw) # printing user_pw just to make sure the loop is working - it is
    
        if( user_pw_hash == correct_pw_hash ):
            print("Welcome back... your flag, user:")
            decryption = str_xor(flag_enc.decode(), user_pw)
            #decryption = xor(flag_enc.decode(), user_pw)
            print(decryption)
            return
        print("That password is incorrect")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too experienced myself, but I think I know what you're doing wrong. I'll try to give you a small tip that will probably help you solve the problem without giving you the answer full out.

I think where you're going wrong is that you're still asking for input. Since you're comparing a list of possible passwords to the actual possible password, **you don't need to ask for input anywhere in your code**.

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks, I had recently added that input statement. That line of code used to read 

user_pw = x

And the program would complete without giving the flag - indicating that the pwds provided in the list aren't correct - but I expect that one is...

Using the input code only served to confirm to me that I was entering each PW. But I wonder if the IF part of the code after the pw is 'entered'  is being ran right...? 

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Another thing—check your if statements. After your "for" statement, do you want to check the flag only once, or do you want to **check each flag that you're iterating through in the for loop**?

Comment: Yup, need to check each one. That's what I think is not happening...